# iOS Location Reminders "While Using" the app

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I've been working on a new app that leverages the use of location based reminders via geofencing.

As far as I understand, in order to do that, the app must request authorisation via:

```
CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

So far, it works as expected, but I'm curious how for example the "Reminders" app, and others such as Omnifocus only request for "When in use" or:

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

Those apps are still able to provide location based reminders without requesting always authorisation.  I also noticed that these apps won't trigger the "location" icon on the status bar while in background, which my app does.   How do they get these apps to deliver those notifications then?

Thanks!

D

Comment: Well what simpler than testing it out and see if it works with `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer while watching the WWDC CLLocation updates to iOS 8 available here:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=706

Reminders and similar apps work without requiring for AlwaysAuthorization since they take advantage of the UILocalnotification framework changes.   Since iOS 8, it supports Region Based Triggering.

So now if you do not need to actually "Launch" your app in the background and do something when location changes, and just present a notification, you can just use UILocalNotification and RegionBased Triggering.

```
 @NSCopying var region: CLRegion!
```

in iOS8, UILocalnotification has the 'region' property, which correspondes to a CLRegion object.

From Apple docs:
Assigning a value to this (region) property causes the local notification to be delivered when the user crosses the region’s boundary. The region object itself defines whether the notification is triggered when the user enters or exits the region. The default value of this property is nil.

You may specify a value for this property or the fireDate property but not both. Attempting to schedule a local notification that contains both a region and fire date raises an exception.